# Understanding std::accumulate

Tags: c++, stl, accumulate

I want to know why `std::accumulate` (aka reduce) 3rd parameter is needed. For those who do not know what `accumulate` is, it's used like so:

```
vector<int> V{1,2,3};  
int sum = accumulate(V.begin(), V.end(), 0);
// sum == 6
```

Call to `accumulate` is equivalent to:

```
sum = 0;  // 0 - value of 3rd param
for (auto x : V)  sum += x;
```

There is also optional 4th parameter, which allow to replace addition with any other operation.

Rationale that I've heard is that if you need let say not to add up, but multiply elements of a vector, we need other (non-zero) initial value:

```
vector<int> V{1,2,3};
int product = accumulate(V.begin(), V.end(), 1, multiplies<int>());
```

But why not do like Python - set initial value for `V.begin()`, and use range starting from `V.begin()+1`. Something like this:

```
int sum = accumulate(V.begin()+1, V.end(), V.begin());
```

This will work for any op. Why is 3rd parameter needed at all?

Comment: `accumulate(V.begin()+1, V.end(), V.begin());` doesn't work if `V` is empty.

Comment: Another reason is when the total sum will no longer fit into the type so you have to specify a different type that can hold the value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way things are, it is annoying for code that knows for sure a range isn't empty and that wants to start accumulating from the first element of the range on. Depending on the operation that is used to accumulate with, it's not always obvious what the 'zero' value to use is.

If on the other hand you only provide a version that requires non-empty ranges, it's annoying for callers that don't know for sure that their ranges aren't empty. An additional burden is put on them.

One perspective is that the best of both worlds is of course to provide both functionality. As an example, Haskell provides both `foldl1` and `foldr1` (which require non-empty lists) alongside `foldl` and `foldr` (which mirror `std::transform`).

Another perspective is that since the one can be implemented in terms of the other with a trivial transformation (as you've demonstrated: `std::transform(std::next(b), e, *b, f)` -- `std::next` is C++11 but the point still stands), it is preferable to make the interface as minimal as it can be with no real loss of expressive power.

Answer (score 44):

You're making a mistaken assumption: that type `T` is of the same type as the `InputIterator`.

But `std::accumulate` is generic, and allows all different kinds of creative accumulations and reductions.

### Example #1: Accumulate salary across Employees

Here's a simple example: an `Employee` class, with many data fields.

```
class Employee {
/** All kinds of data: name, ID number, phone, email address... */
public:
 int monthlyPay() const;
};
```

You can't meaningfully "accumulate" a set of employees. That makes no sense; it's undefined. But, you can define an accumulation *regarding* the employees. Let's say we want to sum up *all* the monthly pay of *all* employees. `std::accumulate` can do that:

```
/** Simple class defining how to add a single Employee's
 *  monthly pay to our existing tally */
auto accumulate_func = [](int accumulator, const Employee& emp) {
   return accumulator + emp.monthlyPay();
 };

// And here's how you call the actual calculation:
int TotalMonthlyPayrollCost(const vector<Employee>& V)
{
 return std::accumulate(V.begin(), V.end(), 0, accumulate_func);
}
```

So in this example, we're accumulating an `int` value over a collection of `Employee` objects. Here, the accumulation sum *isn't* the same type of variable that we're actually summing over.

### Example #2: Accumulating an average

You can use `accumulate` for more complex types of accumulations as well - maybe want to append values to a vector; maybe you have some arcane statistic you're tracking across the input; etc. What you accumulate doesn't *have* to be just a number; it can be something more complex.

For example, here's a simple example of using `accumulate` to calculate the average of a vector of ints:

```
// This time our accumulator isn't an int -- it's a structure that lets us
// accumulate an average.
struct average_accumulate_t
{
    int sum;
    size_t n;
    double GetAverage() const { return ((double)sum)/n; }
};

// Here's HOW we add a value to the average:
auto func_accumulate_average = 
    [](average_accumulate_t accAverage, int value) {
        return average_accumulate_t(
            {accAverage.sum+value, // value is added to the total sum
            accAverage.n+1});      // increment number of values seen
    };

double CalculateAverage(const vector<int>& V)
{
    average_accumulate_t res =
        std::accumulate(V.begin(), V.end(), average_accumulate_t({0,0}), func_accumulate_average)
    return res.GetAverage();
}
```

### Example #3: Accumulate a running average

Another reason you need the initial value is because that value isn't *always* the default/neutral value for the calculation you're making.

Let's build on the average example we've already seen. But now, we want a class that can hold a *running* average -- that is, we can keep feeding in new values, and check the average *so far*, across multiple calls.

```
class RunningAverage
{
    average_accumulate_t _avg;
public:
    RunningAverage():_avg({0,0}){} // initialize to empty average

    double AverageSoFar() const { return _avg.GetAverage(); }

    void AddValues(const vector<int>& v)
    {
        _avg = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 
            _avg, // NOT the default initial {0,0}!
            func_accumulate_average);
    }

};

int main()
{
    RunningAverage r;
    r.AddValues(vector<int>({1,1,1}));
    std::cout << "Running Average: " << r.AverageSoFar() << std::endl; // 1.0
    r.AddValues(vector<int>({-1,-1,-1}));
    std::cout << "Running Average: " << r.AverageSoFar() << std::endl; // 0.0
}
```

This is a case where we absolutely rely on being able to set that initial value for `std::accumulate` - we *need* to be able to initialize the accumulation from different starting points.

---

In summary, `std::accumulate` is good for any time you're iterating over an input range, and *building up* one single result across that range. But the result doesn't need to be the same type as the range, and you can't make any assumptions about what initial value to use -- which is why you must have an initial instance to use as the accumulating result.

Comment: This point **should** be stressed further. Just the other day I caught a nasty bug where I wanted to do a `float` operation on a vector, but because I simply used `0` as my initial value, the compiler made all operations of type `int` instead.

Comment: Missed an opening curly brace in `auto accumulate_func = [](int accumulator, const Employee& emp)`.

Answer (score 3):

Because standard library algorithms are supposed to work for arbitrary ranges of (compatible) iterators. So the first argument to `accumulate` doesn't have to be `begin()`, it could be any iterator between `begin()` and one before `end()`. It could also be using reverse iterators.

The whole idea is to decouple algorithms from data. Your suggestion, if I understand it correctly, requires a certain structure in the data.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted `accumulate(V.begin()+1, V.end(), V.begin())` you could just write that. But what if you thought v.begin() might be v.end() (i.e. v is empty)? What if `v.begin() + 1` is not implemented (because v only implements ++, not generized addition)? What if the type of the accumulator is not the type of the elements? Eg.

```
std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, [](long count, char c){
   return isalpha(c) ? count + 1 : count
});
```

Comment: `v.begin() + 1` is solved in C++11 with the introduction of `std::next`. On the other hand, the latter point (difference of types between dereferenced iterator and accumulated value) is the most compelling argument I have seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed not needed. Our codebase has 2 and 3-argument overloads which use a `T{}` value.

However, `std::accumulate` is pretty old; it comes from the original STL. Our codebase has fancy `std::enable_if` logic to distinguish between "2 iterators and initial value" and "2 iterators and reduction operator". That requires C++11. Our code also uses a trailing return type (`auto accumulate(...) -> ...`) to calculate the return type, another C++11 feature.