# Good reason for third argument to std::accumulate?

Tags: c++, c++11

I just wrote a small helper function as a wrapper of `std::accumulate`:

```
template <typename FwdIter> inline
auto accumulate(FwdIter begin, FwdIter end) -> std::iterator_traits<FwdIter>::value_type
{
    return std::accumulate(begin, end, std::iterator_traits<FwdIter>::value_type());
}
```

I'm probably overlooking something here. Why isn't this an existing overload of `std::accumulate` ? The function appears so obvious that it can't have been overlooked; someone had a good reason to make that third parameter mandatory.

(See also [Understanding std::accumulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633950/understanding-stdaccumulate) - I understand why you want the ability to provide an initial value, I just don't understand why it is mandatory)

Comment: At a glance I'd say someone forgot it.

Comment: I'd assume that this overload would at least be a `foldl1`, not.. this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So that the template arguments can be deduced.

The declaration is

```
template< class InputIt, class T >
T accumulate( InputIt first, InputIt last, T init );
```

and the only argument to deduce the return value from is `init`. Because it does *not* have to be value type of the iterator.

Yes, it could still *default* to `std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type()`. The committee probably simply didn't think of that.

PS: You confused me with the auto. I thought it was not added because it was not possible in C++03 and overlooked when C++11 was done because it didn't look like needing any change. But it is *not* needed here; the template argument is declared at the time you write return type in the standard position.

Comment: That's not really an argument, though. If you want to use a non-default type, why not pass a type instead of a value: `template<typename T, typename InputIt> T accumulate(...); accumulate<double>(begin, end);`

Comment: @MSalters: Because all function templates in standard library deduce their arguments. Noone expects to specify them. Besides, than you don't save anything anymore -- `accumulate<T>(...)` vs. `accumulate(...,T())`.